# Styling OutlinedInput on focus material ui v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm dealing with the 5th version of material ui trying to style an OutlinedInput with different methods, but i'm still not able to do what i want.
To make it short i want to apply two different styles on focus and no-focus by using css rules, what i succeed to do is the following :

```
 <OutlinedInput
                id="input-with-icon-adornment"
                endAdornment={
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <SearchIcon />
                  </InputAdornment>
                }
                fullWidth
                notched
                sx={{
                  "& .css-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                    borderColor: "black !important",
                    borderWidth: "2px !important",
                  },
                  
                }}
              />
```

but the problem with that solution is that it's applying it for all states (focused or not)
What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the styles like below.

```
<OutlinedInput
        id="input-with-icon-adornment"
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <SearchIcon />
          </InputAdornment>
        }
        fullWidth
        notched
        sx={{
          "&.MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "green"
          },
          "&.MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "red"
          },                    
          "&.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "purple"
          },
        }}
      />
```

Here is working example in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-demo-material-ui-forked-tfq31v?file=/demo.tsx:448-1090)

Comment: Thank you so much ! you saved my code, but could you explain me please the logic behind this ?

Comment: @NABILSFT When you inspect the element you can find all the classes, so after that is a matter of targeting the right element in the usual way you would do it with css. So for example in the first case I had to target the 'MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline' element which is a children of the root. Similar I had to do for the ':hover' state and at the end when the root element gets also the class 'Mui-focused' I targeted the element 'MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline' again. Does it make sense? Thanks